# Why has discussion here gone down?

Tags: discussion, mso-mse-split, participation

In trying to find out which site I could get the pizza hat on, I came across an interesting trend here on Meta Stack Exchange.  Here is the number of posts here on meta that meet the requirements for the 30-minutes-or-less hat, if they were posted during the hat period:

[image: Pizza-worthy graphs over time]

<sup>Thanks to Rolfl for the initial query and Bluefeet for helping with grouping.</sup>

In an incomplete 2008, there were 71 active posts, 2009 had 183! They dropped off a bit afterwards, but this year there have a measly 5, one of which was a dev introducing a new feature.

So why has discussion dropped off like this? Is there anything we can and should do about it?

[Graph query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/259059/5-in-30-minutes-or-less#graph)

[Individual posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/revision/259022/337835/5-in-30-minutes-or-less)

Comment: SO got their own Meta, is what changed.

Comment: MSE used to be MSO, and SO also off into programmers (September, '10), and then there was SU, SF, ... etc.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - That really had no affect on the graph.

Comment: @TravisJ: it does actually; the drop from 2013 to 2014 is caused by that split. Had the OP used smaller bins it'd have been more visible.

Answer (score 5):

As far as more recently: Meta Stack Exchange no longer doubles as a Meta for Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange, so Meta SE no longer sees a lot of the traffic that consistently flooded in from regular Stack Overflow users.

As far as over time: When a site is first born, there is **lots** to discuss. No one ever gets it perfect right off the bat. There are going to be tons of bugs, lots of things that got overlooked, and inevitably lots of discussion about what needs changed, moved around, ditched, etc.

Over time, though, the system and even the people change. As bugs get fixed and features get expanded, naturally there will be fewer things to discuss. At six years strong, a *lot* of policies have been fleshed out rather stringently and we've seen a lot of discussion about issues that rise up time and time again. Everyone has seen the discussions about comments for downvoting, subjective questions, and others. It starts to become more of a process of directing users to the information they need to find rather than fleshing out all the information *again*.

Overall, I don't believe your graph is an accurate representation of "discusson going down" here on Meta, as in, how many answers a question receives within the first 30 minutes is not a good indicator of it. While I'm certain that it has decreased, it over-exaggerates by how much. Your query finds a total of 365 questions which have received at least 5 answers within 30 minutes, while there are actually a total of 3,236 questions which currently stand with at least 5 answers.

Some things you should consider for a much better analysis of discussion patterns here on Meta:

- Not all questions posted here *require* discussion. Bug reports rarely ever require additional input and answers there generally consist of "this is not actually a bug" or "this has been fixed" (in which case, it could be quite some time before that answer comes in).
- Not everyone likes to jump right into a discussion. Some users, especially on controversial posts, would rather wait and observe a new question to see how other users react to it before fully developing a position on their own.
- Discussions require more thought, detail, research, and examples to be well-accepted as a valid argument. Lacking that will only result in a flood of downvotes and a long discussion trying to pry that information out of you, and users have certainly learned that very well over time. The longer processing time for the answer would certainly push many answers over that 30-minute threshold.
- Many long and drawn out conversations occur in the comments here on Meta. Sometimes, if they result in valuable information, they may end up being converted into a full answer.

I'm sure there are many other factors, but those are just some of the big ones off the top of my head.

Comment: I think because this web site difficult to use

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your not asking this question to try to increase your already demanding lead on MSE? In basketball it's sometimes considered rude to run up the score if your already ahead by a lot. Keep that in mind :) There's no way you could not get first place on Meta.SE, just don't even worry about it, you got this in the bag!!

[image]

And to answer your more direct question of why has the activity gone done here, it's because of the Meta.SO/Meta.SE split, like Martijn Pieters mentioned in the comments. So people are asking SO specific questions on Meta.SO now where their question belongs instead of on the network wide Meta.SE.

There's [5595](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=[stackoverflow]+is%3Aquestion) questions tagged SO on Meta.SE. [2516](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=[stackoverflow]+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ayes) of them are closed!

Comment: Yeah, the community really dropped the ball on getting me the pizza hat here.

Comment: Anyway, I'm only tied for 5th network-wide.

Comment: Whaaat? I'm #4?